# codecs module cannot read in text file

Tags: python, codec

I have a text file that I want to convert to base64 on a line by line basis.
Using pandas 1.0.1 and python 3.7
I have a text file consisting of words separated by carriage returns named sampleTEXT.txt
Pandas can read the file and it has data

```
import pandas as pd
words = pd.read_table("sampleTEXT.txt",names=['word'],encoding="utf-8",header=None)
words.head()
---      word
---------------
---0    difference
---1    where
---2    mc
---3    is
---4    the
---
```

The next jupyter cell has this code:

```
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with codecs.open(sampleTEXT.txt, "r", "utf-8") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open(bsampleTEXT.b64, "w", "base64") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

but I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-8aec7c80fc16> in <module>
      1 import codecs
      2 BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
----> 3 with codecs.open(sampleTEXT.txt, "r", "utf-8") as sourceFile:
      4     with codecs.open(bsampleTEXT.b64, "w", "base64") as targetFile:
      5         while True:

NameError: name 'sampleACAD' is not defined
```

I know the file is there and that it's ok because pandas can import it as a dataframe. I know I'm using the correct syntax as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html)

Comment: Put the filename in quotes.

Comment: thank you but now I get this error '
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str'

Comment: Any reason to use the `codecs` module instead of `io` ?

Comment: yes, it gives this error 'TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)'

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work without error but it does not write anything:

```
import io,codecs
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with io.open("sampleACAD.txt",mode="rb") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open("bsampleACAD.b64", mode="w", encoding="base64") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```